# Steps to add datepicker to the bootstrap modal

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a project where i have to add datepicker to the bootstrap modal.I donot know how to add datepicker to the modal popup window. 
    I want the steps to add the datepicker to the bootstrap modal without any error. Can anyone guide me step by step to create a datepicker to the modal.
The following is my modal code :

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_calendar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <form id="event_frm" class="form-horizontal">

         <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Title">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event_Subject" placeholder="Subject">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="body">Body</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event_Body" placeholder="Body">
       </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="start_date">Body</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event_start_date" placeholder="Start Date">
  </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_event">Save changes</button>
       </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And the following is my ajax call for the saving of the form data through ajax:

```
 $('#save_event').click(function() {


var subject =$('#event_Subject').val();
var body =$('#event_Body').val();
var start_date = $('#event_start_date').val();
if($('#event_Subject').val() =='')
{
    alert('subject required'); return false;
}
else
{
    $("#modal_calendar").modal('hide');
}
if($('event_Body').val() == '')
{
    alert('Body required'); return false;
}
else
{
    $("#modal_calendar").modal('hide');
}
if($('event_start_date').val() == '')
{
    alert('Start Date required'); return false;
}
else
{
    $("#modal_calendar").modal('hide');
}    
$.ajax({
          cache: false,
          type: "POST",
          url:"calendar/save_event",
          data :  {'subject' : subject,'body' : body,'start_date' : start_date},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(result){
            if (result!=null){
                }
                }
                });
  });

    });
```

Kindly help me and save my day. Any fiddle with the step by step code can help me and people like me..Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker or https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a datepicker to a field is made really easy with jQuery UI.  Any jQuery widget, such as the 'datepicker' will exist as a function that can be called upon any elements on the page like this:
`$('#event_start_date').datepicker();`

Here is a jsFiddle with your code and the added datepicker:
https://jsfiddle.net/bishbashbosh/9jormmpz/1/

I had to put the code inside a

`$(function() {
. . . 
});`

...so that it will get executed after jQuery and jQuery UI have loaded up.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yaah @bishbashbosh , thank you so much, should i have add any modification in the css ?

Comment: No problem :) No you don't need any extra CSS or changes to your HTML.  You just need to make sure you have the jQuery UI CSS file in a <link> element in your HTML.  In my jsFiddle, I am referencing https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: What do 'Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined' really means..?. I am getting this error

Comment: It means some code you have written, or some code you are calling has an _object_ and is trying to call a method (function) or retrieve a property (value) called _hasTime_ from that object, but the _object_ is undefined (i.e. an empty variable).  If you have the Chrome developer tools open when the error occurs, you should be able to expand the error in the console and work out where it's coming from and maybe work out why it's happening.  If you still get stuck, log it as a new question on stack overflow and maybe someone can help.

Comment: yes , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540578/fullcalendar-events-are-not-rendered-correctly Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

I am suggesting you to use bootstrap-datepicker.js and bootstrap-datepicker.css in ur source code.and follow the following steps:

1).First Add the libruary Files of js and css in ur source code.
In Html Write As:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datepickerDiv" style="width:75%; height:40px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_Input" style="color:#888; height:40px;">
    <div class="input-group-addon cal-addonImg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Js: When You focus on input textfield

```
$("#date_Input").datepicker({
                autoclose:true,
                showOnFocus:true,
                format:'yyyy/mm/dd'
             });
```

It Will help you, I hope so...

Comment: What is the advantage of using bootstrap date picker over other ones?

Comment: If you are using bootstrap in your source code.... and it is feasible solution to use it. while using bootstrap.... otherwise you can find various solution using jquery libruary etc

Comment: What do 'Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined' really means..?. I am getting this error !

Comment: Have you added the all header files? tell me please